# On UiPath how can I extract (from an XML File) the second tag if there are multiple tags with the same name?

Tags: xpath, uipath, uipath-studio

I have an XML File with this characteristics:

```
   <Root>
    <Example>
     <Address> Sesame Street </Address>
     <Address> New York US </Address>
    </Example>
    <Example>
     <Address> Nairobi KE</Address>
    </Example>
   </Root>
```

I want to extract always the second tag (New York US) or the first one if its only one tag. But on UiPath when i try to extract (with Execute XPath activity), it always returns the first one.
Any suggestion on how can i extract the second one or the first if its the only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is you always want the *last* Address element in an Example, which can be accomplished by using the XPath function `last()` in the predicate.

`//Address[last()]`

This selects both the "New York US" and "Nairobi KE" elements.

I'm a bit unclear on the question, but if your intent is to only extract "New York US", you can specify that you only want the last Address in the first Example.

`//Example[1]/Address[last()]`